# Transporting my corn snake from UK to USA

Tags: air-travel, transportation, pets

I am planning to go to the USA for some time and I would like to take my corn snake with me.

It's difficult to find information.

Is it possible to somehow take the snake on the plane with me?

If not, and I'm guessing not, what are my options for transportation?

Comment: I would be a bit worried about the temperature in the hold, as well as possible rough handling.

Answer (score 4):

First, you will need a permit from the [US Fish & Wildlife Service](https://www.fws.gov/le/commercial-wildlife-shipment.html).

Second, you must fly into a designated port.

I don't believe any airline will let you transport a snake in the cabin.  You would need to provide a kennel that is both escape-proof and humane for the animal, and put it in the hold with the other animals.

Personally, [I'm getting tired of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLaX8UvVUQw).

Comment: Interesting and informative. Do you have any authoritative links to back up your answer?

Comment: @JoErNanO -- added.  FWS mentions "commercial" importation, but I don't know if you could get in on your unsupported word "But, Slimey is my pet."